# Нужно ли выделять запятыми обороты, начинающиеся словами "а не"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять запятыми обороты, начинающиеся словами "а не"? Почему нет запятой после слова "прозой" в следующем примере: "Хотя, поверьте, мне гораздо легче стихами, а не прозой изъясняться" (Алексей Корепанов. Книга 1. Прорыв)?

Answer (score 2):

Союз А может быть соединять **однородные члены**, которые разделяются запятыми, а может  относится к обособленному **пояснительному члену**.

1) Хотя, поверьте, мне гораздо легче **стихами, а не прозой** изъясняться (однородные члены разделяются запятой).

2) Рассказывали о нем чудеса; имя Дубровского было во всех устах, все были уверены, что **он**, **а не кто другой**, предводительствовал отважными злодеями (пояснительные отношения, обособление запятыми).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Если отвечать **формально**, то обособление  в таких случаях является авторским решением, это автор может посчитать один из однородных членов  дополнительной информацией  и обособить его.  Если же отвечать **по  существу**, то и **авторское решение зависит от контекста, от речевой задачи**. Это только кажется, что мы можем свободно переставлять слова в предложении, менять их количество, объем и т. д., в действительности  же (1) каждое предложение имеет **определенную мелодику** (как и стихотворный текст),  а (2) содержание высказывания соотносится с его **коммуникативной функцией** (что, кому и зачем  мы говорим). Надо понимать, почему мы хотим выделить на второй план какую-либо информацию, которую мы сообщаем **нашему собеседнику**, причем делается это с учетом его осведомленности в теме.

2) **А теперь о предложениях**. Естественный порядок слов в них изменен, правильнее было бы сказать так: **«Мне гораздо легче читать свои стихи Кате, а не Маше. Мне гораздо легче запоминать стихи, а не прозу»**. (На первом месте прямое дополнение, на втором – косвенное.) И это будут обычные однородные отношения.  **Для чего здесь применена инверсия и обособление – неясно** (вот в стихах инверсия является обычным приемом). Мелодика первого предложения воспринимается с трудом, а второго – не воспринимается вовсе.  **Это надуманные учебные примеры**, далекие от реальности,  и в этом случае сложно говорить о правильности постановки знаков препинания. Поэтому **примеры лучше не выдумывать, а брать готовыми** из художественной литературы или современной публицистики.

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, как отличить эти два случая, почему стихи и проза - однородные члены, а он и кто другой - нет. Не в том ли разница, что в одном случае - подлежащее, а в другом - нет?

Comment: (1) Однородные члены (интонация перечислительная) независимо друг от друга раскрывают какую-либо тему (к ряду однородных членов можно подобрать обобщающее слово, например:  стихи и проза - это два основных жанра художественной речи). (2) Уточняющие и пояснительные члены называют один предмет два раза (второе слово уточняет или поясняет первое): он  и  Дубровский - это  одно лицо (интонация вставочная, выделение паузами с двух сторон). Однородными и пояснительными могут быть любые члены предложенияю

Comment: Вот простой пример: Миша, а не Маша, вышел погулять. Согласно (1), Миша и Маша - однородные члены, не так ли? Нужна запятая после "Маша"? Почему?

Comment: Лучше так: Миша, а не Маша, сегодня дежурит по классу. Здесь мы имеем дело с ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОЙ конструкцией со значением добавочного сообщения. Некоторые лингвисты пользуются понятием "одноименные члены". Одноименные члены однородны грамматически (отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, относятся к одному и тому же слову), а вот по смыслу они могут быть однородными, неоднородными, уточняющими, пояснительными, присоединительными, обобщающими.

Comment: В вашем примере нет смысловой однородности, информация о Маше идет вторым планом в качестве дополнительного сообщения. Присоединительные, уточняющие и пояснительные члены всегда обособляются.

Comment: Извините, мне как непрофессионалу трудно применить эти теоретические знания. Для лучшего понимания не хватает примеров. Не могли бы вы прокомментировать: "Мне гораздо легче Кате, а не Маше(,) читать свои стихи.", "Мне гораздо легче стихи, а не прозу(,) запоминать."

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, разбор примеров  в основном ответе.

Comment: Следуя вашему, Sibylla, совету, нашел в интернете слова популярной песни "Кто-то, а не я, кто-то, а не я сложит песню
 завтрашнего дня" - и этот пример поставил меня в тупик. Почему нет запятой перед "сложит"? Неужели здесь однородные подлежащие? Ведь "я" не согласуется со "сложит", т.е. они (подлежащие) не "объединены одинаковыми отношениями к одному и тому же члену предложения" (Источник: http://5-ege.ru/odnorodnye-chleny/)

Comment: Здесь надо поставить запятую (в некоторых редакциях текста она ставится). Сравнить: "Потому что вся нынешняя российская экономическая политика пассивна и ориентирована на ожидание того, что кто-то, а не руководство страны, выстроит современную экономику".  В этих случаях нет двух независимых (однородных) предметов (кто-то, а не он; он, а не кто-то - одна и та же конструкция, которая обособляется).