# Запятая после противопоставления

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении:

И только движение к достижению нового и лучшего, а не имитация развития(,)  вдохновляет человека на долгую жизнь, когда он и себе и окружающим не в тягость, а в радость.

Answer (score 2):

Уже был [близкий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426963/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5).

Руководствуясь логикой, высказанной там Сибиллой, я бы сказал, что *"а не имитация развития"* идёт в качестве дополнения, уточнения. Фраза полноправна и без него (*И только движение вдохновляет...*). Поэтому запятая, на мой взгляд, **нужна.**

> И только движение к достижению нового и лучшего, а не имитация развития, вдохновляет человека на долгую жизнь, когда он и себе и окружающим не в тягость, а в радость.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Искала просто по оборотам "а не" и не нашла этого вопроса...

Comment: Ничего страшного, я тоже мог бы не найти, если б не помнил, что такой видел недавно.